# Bounded Contexts and Aggregate Roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

We are trying to model an RBAC-based user maintenance system using DDD principles. We have identified the following entities:

```
Authorization is an Aggregate Root with the following:
    User   (an entity object)
    List<Authority>    (list of value objects)

Authority contains the following value objects:
    AuthorityType (base class of classes Role and Permission)
    effectiveDate

Role contains a List<Permission>
Permission has code and description attributes
```

In a typical scenario, Authorization is definitely the Aggregate Root since everything in user maintenance revolves around that (e.g. I can grant a user one or more Authority-ies which is either a Role or Permission)

My question is : what about Role and Permission? Are they also Aggregate Roots in their own separate contexts? (i.e. I have three contexts, authorization, role, permission). While can combine all in just one context, wouldn't the Role be too heavy enough since it will be loaded as part of the Authorization "object graph"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Firstly I can't help but feel you've misunderstood the concept of a bounded context. What you've described as BC's I would describe as entities. In my mind, bounded contexts serve to give entities defined in the ubiquitous language a different purpose for a given context.

For example, in a hospital domain, a **Patient** being treated in the outpatients department might have a list of **Referrals**, and methods such as *BookAppointment()*. A **Patient** being treated as an Inpatient however, will have a **Ward** property and methods such as *TransferToTheatre()*. Given this, there are two bounded contexts that patients exist in: Outpatients & Inpatients. In the insurance domain, the sales team put together a **Policy** that has a degree of risk associated to it and therefore cost. But if it reaches the claims department, that information is meaningless to them. They only need to verify whether the policy is valid for the claim. So there is two contexts here: Sales & Claims

Secondly, are you just using RBAC as an example while you experiment with implementing DDD? The reason I ask is because  DDD is designed to help solve complex business problems - i.e. where calculations are required (such as the risk of a policy). In my mind RBAC is a fairly simple infrastructure service that doesn't concern itself with actual domain logic and therefore doesn't warrant a strict DDD implementation. DDD is expensive to invest in, and you shouldn't adopt it just for the sake of it; this is why bounded contexts are important - only model the context with DDD if it's justifiable.

Anyway, at the risk of this answer sounding to 'academic' I'll now try to answer your question assuming you still want to model this as DDD:

To me, this would all fit under one context (called 'Security' or something)

As a *general* rule of thumb, make everything an aggregate that requires an independent transaction, so:

1. On the assumption that the system allows for **Authorities** to be added to the **Authorization** object, make **Authorization** an aggregate. (Although there might be an argument for ditching **Authorization** and simply making **User** the aggregate root with a list of **Authorities**)
2. **Authorities** serve no meaning outside of the **Authorization** aggregate and are only created when adding one, so these remain as entities.
3. On the assumption that system allows for **Permissions** to be added to a **Role**, **Role** becomes an aggregate root.
4. On the assumption that **Permissions** cannot be created/delete - i.e. they are defined by the system itself, so these are simple value objects.

Whilst on the subject of aggregate design, I cannot recommend these [articles](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011) enough.

Comment: Once again thank you David. Your statement "bounded contexts serve to give entities defined in the ubiquitous language a different purpose for a given context" makes it clear to me.  I guess what made it confusing for me at the start was the requirement of having to go through the AR in order to access one of the EO/VOs in it. It was confusing because, as you mentioned, Role was also an AR referenced inside the Authorization AR.  We are going to the RBAC exercise just to get the hang of using DDD. The other contexts we're working on are I think suitable to apply DDD to.

Comment: No problem. One other piece of advice I'd give is: **Let aggregates reference other aggregates by referencing their ID, not the aggregate itself**. If you read the articles I've suggested it explains why.

Comment: i like the example,let me understand context clearly